# SQL Server : wildcard penalty

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, wildcard

I need to know if SQL Server will have a significant performance penalty for using wildcard or duplicating the same filter in a `WHERE` clause.

I will have 2 variables in `WHERE` statement which are controlled by stored procedure code. I need to know if these queries will cause performance problems

Listing 1

```
declare @filter1 varchar(20)
declare @filter2 varchar(20)
(...)
set @filter2 = @filter1
(...)
select Col1, Col2, Col3
from Table1
where Col1 like @filter1 or Col1 like @filter2
```

Listing 2

```
declare @filter1 varchar(20)
declare @filter2 varchar(20)
(...)
set @filter2 = '%'
(...)
select Col1, Col2, Col3
from Table1
where Col1 like @filter1 and Col1 like @filter2
```

I know you may question why I'm turning to such strange code. I just have different number of filters depending on first variable passed to stored procedures and I need to arbitrarily assign second filter. But sometimes that second filter is not needed.  I looked at using `CASE` in `WHERE` clause but despite positive feedback on this portal, `CASE` will not work here.

Comment: You may want to look into using dynamic SQL and EXEC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to remember about databases is that performance is almost entirely driven by **indexing**. Good indexing and usage = good performance. Bad indexing or usage = bad performance. A whole lot of what you do when tuning a query is just writing it to line up better with your indexes, or modifying indexes to line up better with a query.

*Leading wildcards prevent you from using normal indexes at all!* So, yes, there is likely to be a steep performance penalty for this.

Moving beyond wildcards: even an `OR` condition will make Sql Server less likely to use an index. You might consider writing the query like this:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3
from Table1
where Col1 like @filter1

union

select Col1, Col2, Col3
from Table1
where Col1 like @filter2
```

To make it clear to Sql Server that it can use the index, or this:

```
Set @filter2 = COALESCE(@filter2, @filter1)
select Col1, Col2, Col3
from Table1
where Col1 like @filter1 and Col1 like @filter2
```

Again, if possible, only use trailing wildcards. This still isn't great for indexing, but it's better than nothing.

If this is a very large text/varchar(max) kind of column, you should also consider [full-text index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Comment: Just a side note: there are DBMS that can use an index even for a leading wildard. But for SQL Server your statement is absolutely correct.

Comment: Just to complete your answer: you can create a reversed-index to manage leading wildcard. No chance, instead, to improve a double wildcard (leading and trailing)

Comment: Edited in a slight wording tweak to allow for the (rare) exceptions to leading wild cards.